# Php-MySQL UPDATE & INSERT stopped working after upgrading to MySQL 5.5 from 4.1

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

Suddenly GD updated their MySQL servers last night from version 4.1 to 5.5. Now, I just realized that the algorithm to UPDATE or INSERT new rows of data into the table isn't working anymore. This is what I have (I've been using this same algorithm since 2007 with no issues, maybe now is a little outdated):

```
    if($error_msg == "") 
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE ".$db_prefix."cars SET
                stored='".$_POST['stored_year']."-".$_POST['stored_month']."-".$_POST['stored_day']."',
                year='".add_slashes($_POST['year'])."',
                model='".add_slashes($_POST['model'])."',
                type='".add_slashes($_POST['type'])."',
                typemodel='".add_slashes($_POST['typemodel'])."',
                bodystyle='".add_slashes($_POST['bodystyle'])."',
                engine='".add_slashes($_POST['engine'])."',
                trans='".add_slashes($_POST['trans'])."',
                drive='".add_slashes($_POST['drive'])."',
                color='".add_slashes($_POST['color'])."',
                condition='".add_slashes($_POST['condition'])."',
                millage='".add_slashes($_POST['millage'])."',
                vin='".add_slashes($_POST['vin'])."',
                price='".add_slashes(strip_out($_POST['price']))."',
                low='".add_slashes(strip_out($_POST['low']))."',
                high='".add_slashes(strip_out($_POST['high']))."',
                features='".$features_total."',
                comments='".add_slashes($_POST['comments'])."',
                mk_comment='".add_slashes($_POST['mk_comment'])."',
                title_page='".add_slashes($_POST['title_page'])."',
                certified='".add_slashes($_POST['certified'])."',
                sold='".add_slashes($_POST['sold'])."',
                sold_txt='".add_slashes($_POST['sold_txt'])."',
                se_index='".add_slashes($_POST['se_index'])."',
                one_owner='".add_slashes($_POST['one_owner'])."',
                special= '".$special."'
            WHERE id=".$_GET["id"];

    if(@mysql_query($sql)) die(header("Location: index.php?status=update"));
else
    $error_msg = "Record was not updated because of invalid data posted.";
}
```

I just get:
"Record was not updated because of invalid data posted."

It is not showing any other error. I was just reading this [post](http://oscarvalles.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/mysql-insert-statement-does-not-post-in-godaddy-acct-mysql-50/) where it says that as from MySQL 5.0, you should include the database name before the table name $sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`columnOne`, `columnTwo`)... but not sure.

If you have an idea of why this UPDATE isn't working anymore, I would really appreciate any help.

---

**Edit:** Taken from OP's comment: (for those wondering on the usage of the `add_slashes()` function).

`add_slashes` is inserted from the local functions file.

```
function add_slashes($string) { 
        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
                return addslashes($string); 
        else
                return $string; 
}
```

**Edit:** I tried adding **mysql_error()** and I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition='good', millage='7087', vin='2BFKOPP25B5YR501', price' at line 12

Comment: For one, it looks like the function name is actually `add_slashes`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: I had some issues with DATE,DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP columns when upgrading, not sure if any of your columns are of those type (looks like `stored` is a DATE type). I fixed it by dropping the column and re-adding it. here is a link with some more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: When `mysql_query()` fails, you should include `mysql_error()` in the error message so you see the reason. Can you post what `echo $sql` shows and what the error message is?

Comment: Retrieve the value of `$sql` right before you run the query and test the query by itself to get the actual error message.

Comment: A.O.: yeap, $stored is DATE type. If I drop the column as you suggest, and re-add it then, what's going to happen with the data already inserted in it? I checked the link "2.11.1.1 Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5" but it doesn't say something about inconsistencies with the DATE function. I also avoided that line in the UPDATE process (// stored='".$_POST['stored_year']."-".$_POST['stored_month']."-".$_POST['stored_day']."',) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar I tried again adding mysql_error() at the end, I was doing it in the wrong way, and now I'm getting this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition='good', millage='7087', vin='2BFKOPP25B5YR501', pr' at line 12`

Comment: What could be wrong with the SQL syntax? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `condition` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html which is most likely a/the reason @JohnA10

Comment: @Fred-ii- BINGO! respect! thank you so much master! I just avoided `condition='".add_slashes($_POST['condition'])."',` and it works now. It seems I have a lot work changing the name of this variable in the database and everywhere it is used, ouch!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. @JohnA10 I posted an answer a while ago if you want to close 'er up that way it won't remain as unanswered. Cheers - There's an example with the backticks in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`condition` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html which is most likely a/the reason.

Try (using backticks around the word `condition`)

```
`condition`='".add_slashes($_POST['condition'])."',
```

*Plus*, if at all possible, try and use another word for the column name.

---

In past MySQL releases, `condition` was not a reserved word at the time which explains why it worked for you back then when you were using 4.1 and have since upgraded to 5.5.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html

`condition` became a reserved word as of version 5.0

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: One million thanks again, it is working now (momentarily while I change the name of the column), adding the backticks `` to `condition`

Comment: You're very much welcome John. It's always a good feeling finding a solution. @JohnA10 Cheers

Comment: Added note John: You may want to start working on some new code in the near future, if and when `mysql_*` functions get (*eventually*) deleted from future PHP releases, should GoDaddy upgrade theirs sometime and get a surprise you're not going to like. Look under my **Footnotes** about it. @JohnA10

Comment: Thanks a lot for the footnote. Yeap, I was reading a little bit about it, and I know it is something I have to address soon. I'm kind of worried about it because I'm not sure yet how I'm going to do it, I'm don't know too much about mysqli, mysql_query function is used virtually in the entire site in hundreds of pages, and not sure if this means I have to re-edit the entire MySQL code. As you saw it, I'm not a MySQL guru :|

Comment: You're welcome John. If and when, all you really need to do is simply add an `i` in it. For example: `mysql_query()` would be `mysqli_query()` etc. However when closing a connection, DB connection variable needs to be inside the function. I.e.: In `mysql_*` you didn't need a DB variable to close it `mysql_close();` but in `mysqli_*` you do `mysqli_close($con);` Plus, some other functions will also need DB connection passed, such as  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` being `$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['var']);` as opposed to `mysql_real_escape_string()` you didn't need to. @JohnA10

Comment: Got it, really thanks Fred for the advice and your help! I'll check it out carefully and see if I can figure it out d: Thank you!

Comment: @JohnA10 You're welcome John, always glad to help out. Cheers